# The Vixen and The Hound

Tags: word

This story concerns a vixen and a hound who begin as piqued foes but end making jazz. The mahogany fox, reckoned a plague by squads of hunters, evades dogs' jaws zestfully. The hound, who likes to catch Z's more than vixens, is judged by most to be quite the failure. The vixen (her name is Fizz) quietly engineers a jape she can irk the canine with (his name is Bud). The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy hound. The dog, discomposed by the fox's hijinks, vows to quit lazing. He works out: jogs on the spot, boxes zephyrs, mimes croquet -- develops fitness. Later, he's spotted waltzing quickstep in a dive juke by the fox. Fizz and Bud, dancing to jive quirkily, wax fond -- and ere long are happily married.

---

The method by which this puzzle was constructed is also its solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this text, each sentence

> has all the letters of the alphabet but one. The missing letters are **LIPOGRAMS**, a word meaning "writing where some particular letter is omitted".